# how to do size_t multiplication

Tags: c++, c

```
size_t size, reshape_size;
size = somemethod()
for (size_t index = 0; index < *dim; ++index)
        reshape_size = reshape_size*shape[index];
if (reshape_size == size){
...
```

I get a error

```
error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘size_t {aka long unsigned int}’)
```

So how do I do the multiplication? I have to compare two size_t afterwards as seen.

Comment: Looks like a typo what are you multiplying `dim` by?

Comment: Also, why C and C++, which one are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem isn't the multiplication, but dereferencing `dim`. Is `dim` a pointer? **No**. What is `index < *dim` supposed to mean?

Also, I think you (wrongly) assume that `size_t size, reshape_size;` will be initialized to something. Because `reshape_size = reshape_size*shape[index];` is undefined, since `reshape_size` wasn't initialized.